# 60 fps vs 50 fps in 24 fps timeline slow motion difference

Tags: slowmotion

If my math is correct, shooting 60 fps, playback 24 fps will allow me 2,5x slower motion.

Shooting 50 fps than should give me about 2x slower motion.

Is that difference significant in real time, or it's just in theory?

Will 60 fps bring “slower” slow motion over 50 fps on the same 24 fps timeline?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is noticable but the question is if it is worth it.
Many low-end cameras compress High Framerate videos more than "normal" framerate videos, thus you loose quality.

So best thing in this case is just to try it out, if you think that the quality loss if worth the slight slower speed

Answer (score 0):

The difference in the speed of playback *up to 5 %* is considered as *tolerable, unnoticeable.*

By this rule of thumb 60 fps compared with 50 fps are *too different (20 %)*.

As an example of a tolerable difference is a common case of playing back a movie with 24 fps on TV set in Europe with 25 fps (4 % difference in speed).

Comment: Where does this rule come from? Do you have a reference?

Comment: I think we do not really understand each other. 
Let's say, I want slow motion of my dog
I will record him with 2 cameras, one will be set to 60fps, another to 50fps

both of them will be slowed down and played back in 24fps timeline

Will original 60fps fotage show my dog in slower speed ?

Comment: "Will original 60fps footage show my dog in slower speed ?" — of course. It will play at 24/60 = 0.4 of its original speed, while 50fps video will play at 24/50 = 0.48 of its original speed, presuming that you slow down the original video without losing frames or creating fake frames. Whether the difference is significant or not is totally subjective.

Comment: @Rusty, you're right with your calculation and objective consequences. But we humans are not so different. It's 20 % difference, so it recognized everyone.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, no, probably, probably not... depends.**

Ok, you have two questions here. Yes, a 60fps clip will have more frames per second, pretty self-explanatory.

But the other question is pretty subjective.

In real life (Not real-time), it can be a total disaster, for example, if you are working on a music video clip where dancers were shot at the wrong speed given a specific beat.

Another case would be where you need to fill a specific timeline with the clip, and having fewer frames could not be enough to fill that space.

But if your clip does not have a specific element that can be timed accurately, it does not matter, because our perception is not that exact. It can be just a cool moment in our video.

Even better, modern programs have some neat features to re-warp the frames, it invents new frames with the information on other frames. So, now days is a lot easier to adapt slow motion and time warp clips in the videos.